# Output the line number from the SCSS file in compiled CSS with gulp-sass

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I've recently switched from Grunt to Gulp task runner.

Is it possible to output as comment the line number in the compiled CSS files that would indicate where a given rule came from in the SASS file?

Such feature was enabled by default when I was using grunt-contrib-compass module.

Now I'm using gulp-sass for compiling my sass files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is possible you need to pass it the right options:

```
.pipe(sass({
  sourceComments: 'map',
  sourceMap: 'sass',
  outputStyle: 'nested'
}))
```

Comment: I'm only wondering why wouldn't these option be listed on gulp-sass git repository's description here [git repo](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass) or here [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass). Or are these options not gulp-sass related ?

Comment: the options are part of node-sass since this is what gulp-sass uses under the hood, they are not gulp-sass specific. For a full list of options available you can check out the node-sass docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

Answer (score 0):

You need to init `gulp-sourcemaps` as the following:

```js
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

function buildStyles() {
  return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
}

exports.buildStyles = buildStyles;
```

then you'll get nice embedded references to your source scss:

[image]

check docs https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass